# Android unable to ask storage permission for android 13 devices

Tags: android, user-permissions

In my Android project, I am asking the user to open the camera. Along with that, I am also asking to ask for storage permission. The permission is working for Android version 12 and less but for Android versions greater than 12, it's not working.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**Fragment**

```
siteSnapButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (siteImagesCount >= 10) {
            Common.showToast(getActivity(), "you have taken maximum site snaps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return;
        }
        currentCameraActionRequest = Constants.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_SITE;
        if (checkCameraPermission()) {
            if (checkStoragePermission()) {
                openCamera();
            }
        }
    });

public boolean checkStoragePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        return true;
    }
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have storage permission; ask for it
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // User previously denied permission; explain why it is required
            showAlertDialogForPermissions("Storage Permission is required",
                    "You previously denied storage permission, but it is needed in order to save images and files. Go to permissions?");
        } else {
            // Request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_STORAGE_REQUEST_FOR_CAMERA_CODE);

        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Constant Class**

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_STORAGE_REQUEST_FOR_CAMERA_CODE = 777;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you would have read only a few pages tagged `android` you would know that for Android 13+ devices one does not request these permissions anymore.

Comment: @blackapps then what for Android 13- ?

Comment: android studio is just the IDE you're using to build your app, it's quite irrelevant to your question, so i've removed it. no answer you get will be impacted by the fact that you're using android studio

Comment: why do you think you need this permission to access external storage?, is your App a generic file manager? Otherwise there are other ways to store files that are not being restricted by Google.

Comment: Nothing for Android 13+. I see you still did not read some pages.

Comment: @Andrew, Google does not restrict writing files to all public directories on external storage. And for Android 13+ devices one does not need any permission to do so.

Comment: Restrict was probably the wrong word, a better word should have been Desire for your app to be more privacy focused and and not randomly save files all over the file system. Some of this does not affect what you can do to your files but does affect what you do to files created by other apps. It was more restricting how you do things and not some much restrict what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for the permissions

[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

> Note: If your app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.R or higher, this permission has no effect.

[READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

> Note: Starting in API level 33, this permission has no effect. If your app accesses other apps' media files, request one or more of these permissions instead: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, READ_MEDIA_AUDIO. Learn more about the storage permissions that are associated with media files.

You can see that Google have restricted the effectiveness of these permissions by giving them both no effect.

You are not restricted from writing your files to external storage.

So a possible solution is to change `checkStoragePermission` to

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 32) {
        return true;
    }
```

As you have already set in your Manifest the maximum api level they will work at to `android:maxSdkVersion="32"`